# Pull Request show lot of changes after revert commits

Tags: git, git-merge, revert, repo

I worked on a branch `feature`.
I wanted to merge it to `develop`, so I did `pull origin develop` in `feature` before.

After that, I realized I had to push `feature` to `staging` instead of `develop`.

So I revert the last two commit and pushed them to the repo. But my pull request show me a **lot of** changes, as if I had did the changes of the merge mysself.

Any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

> So I revert the last two commit and pushed them to the repo

A revert was not necessary: you could reset your staging branch to before the last merge (from the improper `pull`), switch branch, and redo the `git pull`.

In your case, if nobody has pushed to staging, you can still reset locally, and force push the staging branch, to restore it to its previous state.